Get/Set Parameter of array type
I implemented a WebUI for ROS2 Jazzy using Angular 18. I implemented a component to get and set parameters on the ROS parameter service and I cannot seem to get it to work with the array types (bool_array, int_array etc.) but only for basic types (int, string, bool etc.).
The code in question:
private getParameterValue(param: ROSLIB.Param): Promise<any> {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    console.error('Parameter get operation timed out');
    reject(new Error('Parameter get operation timed out'));
  }, 5000); // 5 second timeout

  param.get(
    (value) => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      resolve(value);
    },
    (error) => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      this.publishService.publishRosoutMessage(
        createRosoutMessage({level: ErrorLevel.ERROR, message: `Error getting parameter value: ${error}`,}).message);
      reject(error);
    }
  );
});

}
Parameters are all initialized with the correct name on the parameter server like this:
const param = new ROSLIB.Param({
  ros: this.connectionService.getRos(),
  name: config.name,
});

The rosbridge_server dies (or more specifically the rosapi-node-2) with the following message:
[rosapi_node-2] Traceback (most recent call last):
[rosapi_node-2]   File "/opt/ros/jazzy/lib/rosapi/rosapi_node", line 329, in <module>
[rosapi_node-2]     main()
[rosapi_node-2]   File "/opt/ros/jazzy/lib/rosapi/rosapi_node", line 321, in main
[rosapi_node-2]     rclpy.spin(node)
[rosapi_node-2]   File "/opt/ros/jazzy/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rclpy/__init__.py", line 240, in spin
[rosapi_node-2]     executor.spin_once()
[rosapi_node-2]   File "/opt/ros/jazzy/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 827, in spin_once
[rosapi_node-2]     self._spin_once_impl(timeout_sec)
[rosapi_node-2]   File "/opt/ros/jazzy/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 822, in _spin_once_impl
[rosapi_node-2]     raise handler.exception()
[rosapi_node-2]   File "/opt/ros/jazzy/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rclpy/task.py", line 239, in __call__
[rosapi_node-2]     self._handler.send(None)
[rosapi_node-2]   File "/opt/ros/jazzy/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 508, in handler
[rosapi_node-2]     await call_coroutine()
[rosapi_node-2]   File "/opt/ros/jazzy/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 447, in _execute
[rosapi_node-2]     response = await await_or_execute(srv.callback, request, srv.srv_type.Response())
[rosapi_node-2]                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[rosapi_node-2]   File "/opt/ros/jazzy/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 111, in await_or_execute
[rosapi_node-2]     return callback(*args)
[rosapi_node-2]            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[rosapi_node-2]   File "/opt/ros/jazzy/lib/rosapi/rosapi_node", line 261, in get_param
[rosapi_node-2]     response.value = params.get_param(
[rosapi_node-2]                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[rosapi_node-2]   File "/opt/ros/jazzy/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rosapi/params.py", line 157, in get_param
[rosapi_node-2]     return dumps(value)
[rosapi_node-2]            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
[rosapi_node-2]   File "/usr/lib/python3.12/json/__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
[rosapi_node-2]     return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
[rosapi_node-2]            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[rosapi_node-2]   File "/usr/lib/python3.12/json/encoder.py", line 200, in encode
[rosapi_node-2]     chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
[rosapi_node-2]              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[rosapi_node-2]   File "/usr/lib/python3.12/json/encoder.py", line 258, in iterencode
[rosapi_node-2]     return _iterencode(o, 0)
[rosapi_node-2]            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[rosapi_node-2]   File "/usr/lib/python3.12/json/encoder.py", line 180, in default
[rosapi_node-2]     raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
[rosapi_node-2] TypeError: Object of type array is not JSON serializable

Is anyone who can help out? Are array type parameter values not supported by Roslib.js?
